# Calling prepare() after stop() on MediaPlayer throws IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, playback, state-machine

According to the [state machine diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), the following code should be fine (after properly initializing the MediaPlayer instance):

```
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

But it results in an IllegalStateException on the last call to prepare(). Why?

Note: I realize these three lines of code in isolation are useless, but it illustrates the problem I am having.

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Looks like this is not happening on another device. When I get the original device back I will post an update.

Answer (score -1):

Probably cause you didnt call start() before?

A MediaPlayer when ready will not start automatically, you must call start() so it can play it content.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, and why should I call start?

Comment: For the opposite reason you would call stop()

Comment: The diagram clearly shows that you can call stop once the player is prepared. You don't need to start it.